# Can I bolt over an existing ledger board?

Tags: deck, pergola

I am rebuilding my pergola and all that remains of the previous structure is the 2x10 ledger board, which is bolted through the fascia into what I assume must be the brick wall behind.Taking the thing off will be hard - it's on there pretty good.

Assuming that the existing board itself is sound (so far it appears to be) is there a good reason not to keep it in place and use it to anchor a new (and actually lighter) structure? Would it be preferable to bolt a new board *through* the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

When a thing is built well, it should be hard to dismantle.

If the existing ledger board is level, sound, and properly connected, I can't see any reason why not to reuse it.

Comment: Well it looks like about the only thing in this house that is well built. I just bought the place, and it's like a museum of half-assed DIY projects.

It certainly isn't level. The old pergola was meant to slope off to the side, but it wasn't enough to actually draw off either rain or leaf litter. It's big enough that I can still use it as level, but I'll have to give it a cosmetic cover and secure joists all the way through.

Comment: Well if it's out of level and you want it level you can do one of two things.  1) Shim it.  2) Get a bigger lever to unbolt it.